# Get image asynchronously using MemoryStream and ASP.NET MVC (with AJAX)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following model with the following properties:

- Source (MemoryStream type)
- Title (file name, string)

I created an action:

```
public ActionResult GetPreview(){
  MyModel model = _myPreviewManager.GetPreview();

  return Json)
      new {
          Src = model.Source,  // also I tried-> new FileStreamResult(model.Source, "image/png")
          Name = model.Title
      }
  )
}
```

and my ajax

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   type: "json",
   success: function(result){
      if(result) {  $("img").prop("src", result.Src); }
   }
});
```

But obviously is not working...

How to achieve to load asynchronously image using a MemoryStream as source ?

Thanks

Comment: what does `result.Src` hold?

Comment: a `MemoryStream` object

Comment: Are you trying to use convert memoryStream to Json object and then return Json object. Here is the link  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2a9c6bc5-4bf0-46e3-ad44-35e4fdf6803d/how-to-convert-stream-to-json-object . Hope this help